# Carrot_planner what algorithm it use

Tags: navigation, ros-noetic, base-global-planner, carrot-planner

At first i've tried global planner for my project, just because i can use different algorithms for path planning. But then i found out that carrotPlanner is more suitable for my project although i cant find any documentation about which algorithm carrot planner use. I have to know cause i must mention it in my thesis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The carrot planner is barely an "algorithm" - and so you won't find any references to an academic paper about it. The approach is described in detail on the ROS wiki (http://wiki.ros.org/carrot_planner):

> The planner takes a goal point from an external user, checks if the
> user-specified goal is in an obstacle, and if it is, it walks back
> along the vector between the user-specified goal and the robot until a
> goal point that is not in an obstacle is found"

[image]

Comment: I've noticed that the DWA_local_planner is trying to follow the vector carrot_planner creates between goal point and robot . So if i have to guess, carrot planner is an algorithm that just creates a vector between those 2 point in the map and THEN the local_planner takes action. Is that method computational heavy, cause i don't see many people prefer  it. Although in my case i find it more accurate in navigation cause it eliminates any weird turn or zig zags resulting from the path planning process